# How do Metropolis-Hastings algorithms ensure the constructed MC has the limiting distribution?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo

When looking back at the Metropolis-Hastings algorithms, I think I have been missing the most important point:

> How do Metropolis-Hastings algorithms ensure the constructed MC has a
>   limiting distribution same for all initial distributions?

From what I have read, the algorithms try to construct a MC that has the target distribution being a stationary distribution and with respect to which the MC is reversible. However, a stationary distribution may not be the limiting distribution, and it is the limiting distribution only when the limiting distribution exists. For example, for a finite state MC, the limiting distribution exists if and only if the MC is irreducible and aperiodic. However, I haven't seen a description of the Metropolis-Hastings algorithms that states explicitly how existence of the limiting distribution can be ensured by properly choosing the proposal/auxiliary MC and accept/reject probabilities at each iteration.

Comment: @Procrastinator: My post is asking this: how do you know the constructed MC by MH has the limiting distribution? In other words, what does MH do to ensure the distribution of $X_t$ will converge as $t \to \infty$? Without knowing that, no matter how long you run the algorithms, the distribution may even not converge!

Comment: Yes, but this is the first thing you have to check when you propose a new sampler. And this is, of course, well-known. Then, [Hastings (1970)](http://www.isds.duke.edu/~scs/Courses/Stat376/Papers/Basic/Hastings1970.pdf) is the best reference is you want the technical details.

Comment: How do you "check" this first thing? Thanks for the discussion and the reference.

Comment: The basic idea is to prove that the algorithm produces an ergodic Markov chain that satisfies the detailed balance property with respect to the *desired distribution* and therefore it produces the *desired samples*.

Comment: What do the MH algorithms do to ensure the constructed MC is ergodic (in finite state case, ergodic iff irreducible and aperiodic)? Without having taken any step for that purpose, it is not meaningful to prove the constructed MC is ergodic because it may not be, right?

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but I don't think MH produces a markov chain which converges to an equilibrium. To get the sampling there is no need for the result markov chain to converge. The term ergodic sometimes only refers to the ergodic theorem which doesn't assume aperiodic

Comment: @Tim This requires a longer answer which you can find in the reference I posted previously. All of these properties are proven there.

Comment: @colinfang: In finitely many state MC case, the limiting distribution exists, if and only if the MC is irreducible and apreridoic, which is in turn if and only if the MC is ergodic. If there are infinitely many states, things may be different, and I don't know if ergodic is necessary and sufficient for existence of the limiting distribution. Existence of the limiting distribution is the main point that the M-H algorithms or even of all the MCMC methods have to ensure, I think.

Comment: @colinfang     You are wrong. MH algorithm produces a markov chain which converges to an equilibriun distribution. If the algorithm would not converge to an equilibrium distribution, then it would be of no use. For example, if I want a sample from posterior distribution, then I have to take a sampler that would produce a sample from that posterior distribution and not something else.

Comment: @Tomas I know I maybe very wrong, but still I would like to argue: MH produces a markov chain which has target distribution as invariant distribution and suitable for ergodic theorem, that said, for a long run the average appearance of any states follows the target distribution. It is well known that MH's sampling is never not independent, however if a markov chain converges, it would result in independent distributions in a long run.

Comment: @colinfang     Converged chain does not produce independent samples from target distribution - it is still a markov chain. As I understand, we just "pretend" that samples are independent and live with that. For example in adaptive MCMC algorithms (a la Haario), the dependencies are even stronger.